# How do use node-qunit?

Tags: qunit

The info on this page seems less-than-forth-coming -- https://github.com/kof/node-qunit. I've got a setup where I installed nodejs and installed the node-quit module. I have test runner and executed the command `node /path/to/runner.js`. Below is an example of my setup. Any ideas or examples on how to do this or maybe I'm using it wrong. I previous ran qunit tests using Rhino and EnvJs without any issues but I figured I try nodejs since I using it for other things and the packaging system can be scripted in my build. Maybe I missing an option to node to include Qunit or some environment variable not set -- that would make sense.

**File Structure**

```
node/
public/
  js/
    main.js
tests/
  js/
    testrunner.js
    tests.js
```

**Installation**

```
cd node
npm install qunit
```

This will now update the file structure.

```
node/
  node_modules/
    qunit/
```

**tests/js/testrunner.js**

```
var runner = require("../../node/node_modules/qunit");
runner.run({
    code : "/full/path/to/public/js/main.js",
    tests : "/full/path/to/tests/js/tests.js"
});
```

**tests/js/tests.js**

```
test("Hello World", function() {
    ok(true);
});
```

**Command**

```
node tests/js/testrunner.js
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you need to use full paths to the `main.js` and `tests.js` files and also include a relative path to the `qunit` module. I updated the code above as an example for others.